# What laws direct marketing obeys?

Tags: statistical-significance, marketing

I am starting a new product. I need 100 clients to be viable, out of a market of 12000 target companies.

I'm doing direct marketing in 2 steps: Call / Emailing.

After 50 calls, I collected 30 emails.
Out of 30 emails, I got 37.5% opens, 13.6% clicks, and 0% new customers.

But where should I stop?

My guess is the following:
I need 1% of the market. I should expect 1% returns. This calls for 100 attempts leading to 1 return.

But I'm lost right here: What is the accuracy of 100 attempts? Does it say: "You have 0 returns on 100 attempts, you underdo your target with 90% certainty", or "95% certainty", or "50% certainty"?

I feel I need at least 90% certainty. So, where should I stop?

Thank you

Comment: Is there anything I can do to better specify the question? I expected at least a clue on which statistical law to follow. I could find the remainder next, if I dug deep in my statistics archives...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need consider is "standard errors" around your estimates. This is essentially the level of noise around your measurement (signal). Standard errors become smaller with larger sample size and smaller standard deviation in the data (less heterogeneity).

In the case of % (0/1), you can come up with a conservative standard error by calculating sqrt(0.5*0.5/sample size). Based on this, you can calculate margin of error as follows.

- Margin of error at 99% confidence ~ 1.29/sqrt(n)
- Margin of error at 95% confidence ~ 0.98/sqrt(n)
- Margin of error at 90% confidence ~ 0.82/sqrt(n)

Minha Hwang